# make random numbers evenly in c++

Tags: c++, random

I want to make a list of digits 0,1,2 that is 16 elements long, where each digit appears an equal number of times (plus or minus 1)

So the result would be look like this: `0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0`

This number of times each digit appears

```
0 : 6
1 : 5
2 : 5
```

This is my code, any ideas to make those evenly?

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
{
    int num = rand() % 3;
    if(j == 15)
        cout << num;
    else
        cout << num << ",";
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking but can't you just create an equal number of each value and then do a random shuffle on them?

Comment: You haven't made clear (at least to me) exactly what you mean by "evenly".

Comment: I tried to read the question 3 times. I give up.

Comment: 1) Consider using [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) for generating random numbers instead of an obsolete `rand ()`. 2) Randomness is, well, random. It may not _feel_ random enough, but one can expect such discrepancies from random things.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? (They are different languages.)  C++ has `<random>`, which has higher quality random number generators than `rand()`.  Using `rand() % 3` only uses the lowest order bits of the random number anyway, for which it doesn't try to make an even spread. (It tries to make a spread from 0 to `RAND_MAX`.)

Comment: "where each digit appears an equal number of times (plus or minus 1)" - That's not random. Way too small set for a random sample.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference how big your set is: you can randomly sample it. Note that using `%` destroys uniformity. (See the Pigeon hole principle.)

Answer (score 7):

You could create a list of equal numbers of the values you want and then randomly shuffle them.

Something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    // 16 numbers between 0-3 equally divided    
    for(auto i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        v.push_back(i % 3);

    // mt is a random number generator    
    std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};

    // randomly shuffle the numbers    
    std::shuffle(std::begin(v), std::end(v), mt);

    for(auto i: v)
        std::cout << " " << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 1 1 2 2 0
```

Comment: You can improve on this algorithm, as it will always have 6 0's. Add a random delta: `v.push_back((i+randomDelta)%3)`, where randomDelta initialized to a random number before the for loop.